# Can't verify CSRF token for a jQuery File Upload, IE 9 only, Rails 3 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-plugins, file-upload, csrf

So I am using jquery file upload in a rails 3 app, and everything works beautifully, well except in IE 9 that is.  Only in IE9, when I try to upload a file, I keep getting the 'cant verify csrf token' error in my console. I installed Firebug lite to inspect it, and the correct csrf token is correct and is in the right place in the document (and yes I have my <%= csrf_meta_tags %> tag in the header of layout file). Not sure why it is only doing this in IE 9, has anyone seen this before?

Comment: figured out that the issue is related to IE using iframe transport uploads. I tried changing the option "forceIframeTransport" to true, and then the above problem was replicated in Firefox and other non-IE browsers. Still not sure how to fix it. In the $.ajaxSetup in the jquery.iframe-transport.js file, I tried alerting the json response, but it kept throwing errors and wouldnt let me. So I just tried 'alerting' the "$(iframe[0].body).text()" (which it tries to parse into json, and I got a really weird response. So maybe it's an issue with invalid json, not the csrf token?

Comment: Finally got it!!! The issue was related to IE using iframe transport uploads as opposed to XHR file uploads (which Firefox, Chrome, and Safari all use). If a browser uses iframe transport uploads, the plugin makes a call to a separate method, which generates an iframe a new form in the DOM. This new form did not include the csrf authenticity token, so I had to grab the value from the other form, and append into the new form before it is submitted.

Comment: Please add your own answer and mark it as accepted.

Comment: @ggrillone And how did you grab the value from the other form?

Answer (score 20):

I had the same issue and the comment above from the OP helped me find the answer. Here is what worked for me:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
  ... other options
  formData: [
    { name: 'authenticity_token', value: $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') }
  ]
});
```

Note that the layout file (application.html.erb in Rails 3.2) should have the following:

```
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```